How do I add text that displays underneath an image when the image is in an array? (React Native)(Snacks-expo)
I have an array of images and I want to have an image display randomly on the screen when I press a button, but I want to also have text display underneath the image. Each image I want to have its own respective text underneath. The full image array I have consists of over 200 images.
This is an example of what my code looks like: (The bold italicized portion is where I think the problem is)
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Pressable, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

**//images
const images2 = [
  require('./Characters/image1.jpg'),
  require('./Characters/image2.webp'),
  require('./Characters/image3.webp'),
];**

const stylesIQ = StyleSheet.create({
    BLKButton:
    style={
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      width: 300,
      height: 50,
      borderRadius: 10,
      padding: 10,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center',
      marginTop: 15,
    },
    BGColor:
    style={
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#0096FF',
    },
    Image:{
      height: 400,
      width: 300,
      marginTop: 10,
      marginBottom: 20,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
  });

//IQScreen functionality
const IQScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [randomImage, setRandomImage] = useState(null);
const [imageGenerated, setImageGenerated] = useState(false);

const generateRandomImage = () => {
  if (!imageGenerated) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images2.length);
    setRandomImage(images2[randomIndex]);
    setImageGenerated(true);
  }
};

//Screen Setup
return (
  <View  style={[stylesIQ.BGColor]}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 35, marginTop: 10,  alignSelf: 'center'}}>Intelligence</Text>
    <Image
      source={randomImage}
      style={stylesIQ.Image}
    />
    <View style={[stylesIQ.BLKButton]}>
    <Pressable style={stylesIQ.BLKButton} onPress={generateRandomImage}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
          Choose Your Intellect
      </Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
    <View style={[stylesIQ.BLKButton]}>
    <Pressable style={stylesIQ.BLKButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Strength')}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
          Next Trait: Strength
      </Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  </View>
  );
}

export default IQScreen;


I tried making URI keys, but it still doesn't work
const character1 = require('./Characters/image1.jpg');
const character2 = require('./Characters/image2.webp');
const character3 = require('./Characters/image3.webp');

// Refactored images array
const images2 = [
  { uri: character1, text: 'Character 1' },
  { uri: character2, text: 'Character 2' },
  { uri: character3, text: 'Character 3' },
];

I also tried this approach:
   {uri: require('./Characters/image1.jpg'), name = 'Character1'}


What’s the issue?

I cannot display text underneath an image, when it is chosen at random. All the images are locally on my computer if that helps.

Is the text missing?  Is it out of position?  Is the image rendering as expected?

nothing has rendered

I have created an example:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, Pressable, View, Image } from 'react-native';

const images2 = [
  require('./assets/elon.jpeg'),
  require('./assets/bill.jpeg'),
  require('./assets/mark.jpeg'),
];

const stylesIQ = StyleSheet.create({
  BLKButton: (style = {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 15,
  }),
  BGColor: (style = {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0096FF',
  }),
  Image: {
    height: 400,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});

//IQScreen functionality
const IQScreen = () => {
  const [randomImage, setRandomImage] = useState(null);
  const [imageGenerated, setImageGenerated] = useState(false);

  const generateRandomImage = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images2.length);
    setRandomImage(images2[randomIndex]);
  };

  //Screen Setup
  return (
    <View style={[stylesIQ.BGColor]}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 35, marginTop: 10, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        Intelligence
      </Text>
      <Image source={randomImage} style={stylesIQ.Image} />
      <View style={[stylesIQ.BLKButton]}>
        <Pressable style={stylesIQ.BLKButton} onPress={generateRandomImage}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
            Choose Your Intellect
          </Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <View style={[stylesIQ.BLKButton]}>
        <Pressable style={stylesIQ.BLKButton}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
            Next Trait: Strength
          </Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default IQScreen;

